# Example of LaunchInstance with InstanceSourceDetails interface

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oci-go-sdk

I am looking for an implementation example of LaunchInstanceRequest with the SourceDetails field when it is asking for an interface.

```
instanceRequest := core.LaunchInstanceRequest{}
instanceRequest.SourceDetails = ...
```

I am referring to the following for documentation.

https://godoc.org/github.com/oracle/oci-go-sdk/core#LaunchInstanceRequest

Answer (score 1):

One such example would be to do the following

```
var instanceSD core.InstanceSourceDetails = core.InstanceSourceViaImageDetails{
    ImageId:             common.String("ocid1.image.oc1.iad.aaaaaaaa2tq67tvbeavcmioghquci6p3pvqwbneq3vfy7fe7m7geiga4cnxa"),
    BootVolumeSizeInGBs: common.Int64(50),
}

instanceRequest.SourceDetails = instanceSD
```